# WooCommerce: Show only terms with products in stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I'm using `get_terms` to show a list of terms. It works fine so far.
But I want to hide every term with out of stock products.
If I use `'hide_empty' => true` it wouldn't work because the products are there and published.

Is there a way to add the `_stock` meta field to the `get_terms` function?
Unfortunately I have to use `get_terms`.

Here's my code (it's a lot bigger but that's the part):

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_tax',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'hide_empty' => true,
) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 months ago but maybe it will help someone : I'm facing the same issue and all I found is to make a foreach to unset the empties values.

```
foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'paged' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'publish_date',
        'meta_query' => array( array(
            'key' => '_stock_status',
            'value'    => 'instock',
        ) ),
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $term->term_id
            )
        )

    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if($loop->post_count < 1) {
        unset($terms[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently faced the same issue and ended up doing a native query with [$wpdb](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/)

Here it is for anyone who needs it:

```sql
SELECT wp_terms.term_id, wp_terms.name, wp_term_taxonomy.parent, wp_terms.term_order 
FROM wp_terms
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy 
    ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id
JOIN wp_term_relationships
    ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_terms.term_id
JOIN wp_posts
    ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
JOIN wp_postmeta 
    ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
    AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_stock_status'
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
    AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 'instock'
GROUP BY wp_terms.term_id
ORDER BY wp_terms.term_order
```